# SQL Cube calculate difference

Tags: sql, mdx, olap-cube

In my data I have own row that either says "Ist" or "Plan". This row is also defined as its own Dimension, of course again having those two fields.

Now I would like to have an own measure showing differences between Plan and Ist.

Here is what I tried in the Calculations-section of my cube:

```
create member currentcube.[Measures].[diff] as 0;
Scope [Measures].[diff] ;
this = iif([Plan_Ist].[Plan Ist] = [Plan_Ist].[Plan Ist].&[Ist],- [Measures].[Betrag],[Measures].[Betrag]);
end scope;
```

This does seem to work for the columns "Plan" and "Ist", but the Grand total of the measure diff is the same as the measure Betrag. Also if I am not having "Plan" and "Ist" visible, the measure Diff is 0.

What am I doing wrong? I am a beginner with cube-calculations (as might be obvious) and I am quite stuck...

Thx
Max

Comment: Can you explain further what your desired end result is for the calculation.  You say that you just need a difference, but you are using a scoping function.  What is the purpose of that?

Comment: thanks for your comment, it can be that the function I used was not the right one. However meannwhile I solved this by already importing three different values (Ist, Plan and difference) into the cube by doing the calculation in the view.

Comment: You should write that as an answer and mark it as your choice. That way ou can get some points and we can see the question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I did not get any answer I have choosen the way to split the data already in an view I use to get my data into the cube. So instead of getting one value and "Plan" or "Ist" in an separate column, I now get different value-columns with values for "Plan, "Ist" and "Diff"